# How to upload a file to a folder using webdav?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webdav

I have this webdav code thats creating folders in SharePoint:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(folderAddress);
                request.Credentials = wsLists.Credentials; // CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.Method = "MKCOL";
                response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
```

How can I change the code now to upload a file now to this newly created folder. I think this is a generic webdav question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx)

see also this question for using HttpRequest: [webclient-upload-file-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542853)

or google search for [WebClient.UploadFile webdav](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS330US330&q=WebClient.UploadFile+webdav&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)